# Netmiko - Success but no idea why

Tags: python, netmiko

Hi I have managed to resolve my issue with help from Kirks examples but I dont understand why so the code that is commented out below failed but when I re-wrote it then it successfully sent the 'y' and completed the task? Sorry if this is a naïve question.

```
for i in al:
    nokia = {
    'host': i,
    'device_type': 'alcatel_sros',
    'username': ur,
    'password': pw,
    'session_log': 'netmiko.log',
    }
cmd = 'y'
cmd2 = 'candidate edit'
cmd3 = 'candidate discard'

try:  
    net_conn = ConnectHandler(**nokia)
    #qa = net_conn.send_command('candidate edit', expect_string=i + r">edit-cfg>config>system>security>tacplus#")
    qa = net_conn.send_command_timing(command_string=cmd2, strip_prompt=False, strip_command=False)
    if 'INFO' in qa:
      #bg = net_conn.send_command('candidate discard', expect_string=i + r">edit-cfg>config>system>security>tacplus#")
        bg = net_conn.send_command_timing(command_string=cmd3, strip_prompt=False, strip_command=False)
        if 'WARNING:' in bg:
            net_conn.send_command_timing(command_string=cmd, strip_prompt=False, strip_command=False)
```

This is the debug output (Node name removed).

Failure Output:

```
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'environment no more\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: environment\ no\ more
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: envir
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: onment no more
*A:#
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: environment\ no\ more environment no more
*A:#
DEBUG:netmiko:environment no more
*A:#
DEBUG:netmiko:Exiting disable_paging
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'candidate edit\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: candidate\ edit
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: candi
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: date edit
INFO: CLI There are uncommitted changes in the candidate config.�
*A:>edit-cfg>config>system>security>tacplus#
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: candidate\ edit candidate edit
INFO: CLI There are uncommitted changes in the candidate config.�
*A:>edit-cfg>config>system>security>tacplus#
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
*A:>edit-cfg>config>system>security>tacplus#
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:[find_prompt()]: prompt is *A:NWBY-PX-A1>edit-cfg>config>system>security>tacplus#
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'candidate discard\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: candidate\ discard
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: cand
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: idate discard
WARNING: This action is irreversible. Are you sure you want to proceed (y/n)?
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: candidate\ discard candidate discard
WARNING: This action is irreversible. Are you sure you want to proceed (y/n)?
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:

Successful Output

DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'environment no more\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: environment\ no\ more
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: envir
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: onment no more
*A:#
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: environment\ no\ more environment no more
*A:#
DEBUG:netmiko:environment no more
*A:#
DEBUG:netmiko:Exiting disable_paging
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'candidate edit\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:send_command_timing current output:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: candidate edit
INFO: CLI There are uncommitted changes in the candidate config.�
*A:>edit-cfg>config>system>security>tacplus#
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:send_command_timing final output: candidate edit
INFO: CLI There are uncommitted changes in the candidate config.�
*A:>edit-cfg>config>system>security>tacplus#
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'candidate discard\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:send_command_timing current output:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: candidate discard
WARNING: This action is irreversible. Are you sure you want to proceed (y/n)?
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:send_command_timing final output: candidate discard
WARNING: This action is irreversible. Are you sure you want to proceed (y/n)?
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'y\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:send_command_timing current output:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: y
*A:>config>system>security>tacplus#
*A:>config>system>security>tacplus#
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:send_command_timing final output: y
*A:>config>system>security>tacplus#
*A:>config>system>security>tacplus#
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it worked using the `send_command_timing` and not `send_command` because of how each method works.

The `send_command` is **pattern-based** meaning it searches for a pattern to detect that the command is done *(Default pattern is `#` in the device prompt)*.

> Most probably an `OSError` expection was raised every time you used `send_command` because you didn't change the default value to expect (`expect_string` argument).

On the other hand, `send_command_timing` is **delay-based**; *hence its name (delay ~= timing)*; meaning it doesn't search for any pattern. It waits for some time and continues on with the command after.

You can also investigate this [example](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/EXAMPLES.md#handling-commands-that-prompt-timing) a bit more to have an grasp on how `send_command_timing` works.

The commented code using `send_command` is incorrect. The proper way of using `send_command` should be:

```py
from getpass import getpass
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

nokia = {
    "device_type": "alcatel_sros",
    "host": "",
    "username": input("Username: ").strip(),
    "password": getpass(prompt="Password: "),
    "session_log": "netmiko.log",
}

try:
    with ConnectHandler(**nokia) as conn:
        qa = conn.send_command(command_string="candidate edit", expect_string=r"INFO")
        # print(qa)
        bg = conn.send_command(
            command_string="candidate discard", expect_string=r"WARNING:"
        )
        # print(bg)
        res = conn.send_command(command_string="y")
        # print(res)
except Exception as e:
    ...
```

As you have already noticed, the value you check its membership in the string in the if condition (`if 'INFO' in qa`) is placed in the `expect_string` argument.

Comment: The text of your answer mentions `expect_string` but your code shows `except_string` (with two letters swapped to make a different word).

Comment: @Blckknght You are absolutely right! Thanks for the heads up bro. GitHub CoPilot seems to be not that smart just yet and I need to change my glasses